# colcon test failed in python package

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want do create some tests for my ROS packages. So i started with an example package to begin.
I've created a python package with following command:

```
ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_python --maintainer-name "test user" --maintainer-email test@user.com --license "Apache License 2.0" --description "This is a simple test example" test_package
```

then I build the package with colcon:

```
colcon build --packages-select test_package && source install/setup.zsh
```

I startet the test cases over the colcon test command for my package with:

```
colcon test --packages-select test_package
```

As output i get:

```
Starting >>> test_package
--- stderr: test_package                   

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydocstyle/config.py:6
  Warning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working


-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< test_package [1.07s]

Summary: 1 package finished [1.28s]
  1 package had stderr output: test_package
```

Why are the standard test fails? Did i do something wrong?
I thought it would still work for a few weeks without any warnings
I'm working on Foxy and Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355702/colcon-test-failed-in-python-package/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2020-06-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `test` invocation did not *fail*. There are no test failures. You can check the results using `colcon test-result --all`.

What you are seeing is a Python warning coming from the `pydocstyle` package. The Debian package provided by Ubuntu (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/pydocstyle) version 2.1.1-1 doesn't contain newer fixes from upstream.

You could install a newer version via `pip install --upgrade pydocstyle` but that comes with the downside that the pip-installed version won't be updated automatically (by `apt`) and will overlay potential newer Debian packages released in the future.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on 2020-06-25**:
Thanks for your answer.
is there already a tutorial or example package that gives me some overview?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2020-06-26**:
Depending on what you are looking for there are https://colcon.readthedocs.io/ as well as https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/